# Why tinyint(1) isn't treated as boolean when useInformationSchema is true?

Tags: mysql, mybatis-generator

As common know, mysql treated tinyint(1) as boolean. And so, when I use mybatis generator in my project, I hope the type of some specific fields are boolean. And it did.

But, after I added the statement

```
<property name="useInformationSchema" value="true" />
```

in `<jdbcConnection>` node, the result changed: the tinyint(1) fields are treated as `Byte` in my model.

The statement above is for fetching table comment or some information else.

So the question is how to fix these fields to `Boolean` while keep the `useInformationSchema` node still.

Comment: There is no boolean datatype in MySQL. *mysql treated tinyint(1) as boolean* Who told you such a stupid thing? Boolean may be `true` (`0`) or `false` (`1` or `-1`, software-dependent) whereas the field of `tinyint(1)` datatype may have values in the range from `-128` to `127` (length specification is simply ignored). See [fiddle1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d526593b0a154c97ba86c5c91d030459), [fiddle2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wSuTfry957u5jPUVHQkHWG/0). If somewhere `tinyint(1)` is treated as boolean - it is a client, not MySQL.

Comment: @Akina It's not a stupid thing. Mysql can treat tinyint(1) as boolean.A value of zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

Comment: @binglongli OP have asked about backward convertion.

Comment: update--some Mysql client can treat tinyint(1) as boolean.